# How to define mysql engine or default charset with Ebean automatic DDL generation

Tags: java, mysql, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I'm using Play 2.0 framework with Ebean. It automatically generates DDL scripts. I want to set the mysql engine and the default charset for all created tables.

I cannot figure out how to add "Engine=Innodb DEFAULT CHARSET utf8" using annotations.

Is there a simple way to do this or should I manually create tables using [play evolutions](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/Evolutions/)?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, your better option is to go with Play! evolutions.

But for the utf8 part, you could use something like this in the connection URL :

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SCHEMA_NAME?characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

But for the InnoDB part, I don't have any idea instead using Play! evolutions :(

In a standard JPA, you should use dialect such as `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect`.

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 and innoDB :

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SCHEMA_NAME?characterEncoding=UTF-8&sessionVariables=storage_engine=InnoDB
```